# Converting Excel function into non-array function

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm using a software containing a spreadsheet similar to Excel but it doesn't allow me to use array.
This is a simplified formula I'm using with Excel:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A1:A9>A10)-(A1:A9<A10)))
```

My idea is to recreate array by using formula:

```
IF(A1>A10,1,0)
IF(A2>A10,1,0)
...
```

on range `C10:K10`; and formula:

```
IF(A1<A10,1,0)
IF(A2<A10,1,0)
...
```

on range `L10:T10`

Then proceed with math operations and finish with LOOKUP function to look into "recreated array".
Problem could be a long range i.e. `A1:A100` for number of columns needed, and the need to drag down formula increasing a lot cell formula numbers.

Is there a better way to obtain same result of first formula without the use of array?